# Store into variable result of function VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that makes a particular calculation. Then, I have a subroutine from which I want to call the function and make some stuff with it. I believe I should be returning a value ("counter") at the end of the function and then storing it on the sub, but how do I do that?

```
Function thisFunction(int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer)

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        counter = int1 + int2
    Next

End Function

Sub getResult()

    Dim result As Integer
    result = thisFunction(5, 2)
    MsgBox (result)

End Sub
```

Comment: To return value from function you need to declare it like so `Function thisFunction(int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer) As Integer`  Then to pass it back you put `thisFunction = counter`

Comment: Why is there a for loop in here? You're currently doing the same calculation 10 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, you don't return result with a return statement. You assign the value to the function name. The function does not have to be typed with the "As Integer" by default it will return as variable. So modifying your sample just this way will make it work.

```
Function thisFunction(int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer)

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        counter = int1 + int2
    Next

    thisFunction = counter
End Function

Sub getResult()

    Dim result As Integer
    result = thisFunction(5, 2)
    MsgBox (result)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would specifying your function to have the datatype `Integer` and assigning the value of counter to the function at the end.

```
Function thisFunction(int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer) As Integer

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        counter = int1 + int2
    Next

    thisFunction = counter
End Function
```

I would also like to point out that the function is looping over a statement 10 times redundantly. You should fix it as such:

You would do it as:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    counter = counter + int1 + int2
Next
```

So the previous values are added to the count (if this is what you were planning, otherwise the loop is redundant)

**Edit**
Modified the code for VBA (rather than VB.NET)

Comment: "Return counter" gives me a syntax error, do you know why?

Comment: don't write return counter but `thisFunction = counter` like @Peter said

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function thisFunction(int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer) As Integer

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    counter = counter + int1 + int2
Next i

thisFunction = counter

End Function

Sub getResult()

Dim result As Integer
result = thisFunction(5, 2)
MsgBox (result)

End Sub
```